# survival analysis reference in interaction effect

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I can't change the reference level in my survival analysis. You can see some part of my dataset below and let me go through from the example.

I want reference levels as **H1-M1** but R take it as **H3-M3**, how can I change it?

Ps.: `relevel` doesn't work

```
The red circle is the reference part and that will be 1 V1. Thanks


library(survival)
set.seed(123)
st<-sample(0:1,100, replace = T)
tm<-rnorm(100,20,9)
fm<-sample(c("M","F"),100,replace = T)
age<-rnorm(100,75,10)
level1<-sample(c("M1","M2", "M3"),100,replace = T)
level2<-sample(c("V1","V2", "V3"),100,replace = T)
 
dt<-data.frame(status=st,
               Time= tm,
               Sex=   fm,
               Age=age,
               Level1=level1,
               Level2=level2
               )

dt %>%
  coxph(Surv(Time, status) ~Sex + Age + Level1:Level2 , data = .) %>%
  summary()
```

Te red circle part will be changed to M1 V1. thanks.

[image]

Comment: How is this different to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69426754/how-to-change-reference-level-in-survival-analsiss-interaction-effect)?

Comment: status didn't seemed in my previous question.

Comment: and I have updated the data.frame part

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `interaction` within the formula rather than using ":" you will get the display you expect:

```
dt %>%
     coxph(Surv(Time, status) ~Sex + Age + interaction(Level1 , Level2) , data = .) %>%
      summary()
#-------------------------------
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(Time, status) ~ Sex + Age + interaction(Level1, 
    Level2), data = .)

  n= 100, number of events= 43 

                                     coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)  
SexM                             -0.33279   0.71692  0.34166 -0.974   0.3300  
Age                              -0.01150   0.98857  0.02012 -0.571   0.5677  
interaction(Level1, Level2)M2.V1  0.16097   1.17465  0.68718  0.234   0.8148  
interaction(Level1, Level2)M3.V1 -0.18250   0.83318  0.68056 -0.268   0.7886  
interaction(Level1, Level2)M1.V2  1.34832   3.85096  0.78176  1.725   0.0846 .
interaction(Level1, Level2)M2.V2  0.06087   1.06276  0.68969  0.088   0.9297  
interaction(Level1, Level2)M3.V2  0.97353   2.64726  0.65962  1.476   0.1400  
interaction(Level1, Level2)M1.V3 -0.07056   0.93187  0.88420 -0.080   0.9364  
interaction(Level1, Level2)M2.V3  0.25160   1.28608  0.63625  0.395   0.6925  
interaction(Level1, Level2)M3.V3  0.69068   1.99506  0.74816  0.923   0.3559  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

                                 exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
SexM                                0.7169     1.3949    0.3670     1.401
Age                                 0.9886     1.0116    0.9503     1.028
interaction(Level1, Level2)M2.V1    1.1746     0.8513    0.3055     4.517
interaction(Level1, Level2)M3.V1    0.8332     1.2002    0.2195     3.163
interaction(Level1, Level2)M1.V2    3.8510     0.2597    0.8320    17.824
interaction(Level1, Level2)M2.V2    1.0628     0.9409    0.2750     4.107
interaction(Level1, Level2)M3.V2    2.6473     0.3777    0.7267     9.644
interaction(Level1, Level2)M1.V3    0.9319     1.0731    0.1647     5.272
interaction(Level1, Level2)M2.V3    1.2861     0.7776    0.3696     4.476
interaction(Level1, Level2)M3.V3    1.9951     0.5012    0.4604     8.646

Concordance= 0.6  (se = 0.06 )
Likelihood ratio test= 8.13  on 10 df,   p=0.6
Wald test            = 8.63  on 10 df,   p=0.6
Score (logrank) test = 9.28  on 10 df,   p=0.5
```

I would have personally chosen to use the crossing formula operator, `*`. That way you get "main effects" and interaction coefficients separately. Also the Level1 and Level2 reference levels are as you expect by default.

```
dt %>%
     coxph(Surv(Time, status) ~Sex + Age + Level1 * Level2 , data = .) %>%
     summary()
#--------------
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(Time, status) ~ Sex + Age + Level1 * Level2, 
    data = .)

  n= 100, number of events= 43 

                      coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)  
SexM              -0.33279   0.71692  0.34166 -0.974   0.3300  
Age               -0.01150   0.98857  0.02012 -0.571   0.5677  
Level1M2           0.16097   1.17465  0.68718  0.234   0.8148  
Level1M3          -0.18250   0.83318  0.68056 -0.268   0.7886  
Level2V2           1.34832   3.85096  0.78176  1.725   0.0846 .
Level2V3          -0.07056   0.93187  0.88420 -0.080   0.9364  
Level1M2:Level2V2 -1.44842   0.23494  1.10566 -1.310   0.1902  
Level1M3:Level2V2 -0.19229   0.82506  0.96641 -0.199   0.8423  
Level1M2:Level2V3  0.16120   1.17491  1.07798  0.150   0.8811  
Level1M3:Level2V3  0.94374   2.56957  1.10329  0.855   0.3923  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

                  exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
SexM                 0.7169     1.3949    0.3670     1.401
Age                  0.9886     1.0116    0.9503     1.028
Level1M2             1.1746     0.8513    0.3055     4.517
Level1M3             0.8332     1.2002    0.2195     3.163
Level2V2             3.8510     0.2597    0.8320    17.824
Level2V3             0.9319     1.0731    0.1647     5.272
Level1M2:Level2V2    0.2349     4.2564    0.0269     2.052
Level1M3:Level2V2    0.8251     1.2120    0.1241     5.484
Level1M2:Level2V3    1.1749     0.8511    0.1420     9.718
Level1M3:Level2V3    2.5696     0.3892    0.2956    22.335

Concordance= 0.6  (se = 0.06 )
Likelihood ratio test= 8.13  on 10 df,   p=0.6
Wald test            = 8.63  on 10 df,   p=0.6
Score (logrank) test = 9.28  on 10 df,   p=0.5
```

This means that for comparisons of effects between specific level values would be done with the `predict` function.

Comment: Thanks @IRTFM.. this also worked. dt$Level2 <- factor(dt$Level2, levels = c("V3", "V2", "V1")),
dt$Level1 <- factor(dt$Level1, levels = c("M3", "M2", "M1"))